# MS Visual Studio 2008 - Qt Addin - UI objects prompts do not appear

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt-vs-addin

I create GUI application in QT. I am coding in Ms Visual Studio 2008 instead of Qt Creator, because I am using some external libraries (Xalan, Xerces)...
The question is, how to customize Ms Visual that it shows functions/attributes of UI object (after pressing ctrl+space - class hints). Right now if I press ctrl+space after writing:

*ui->*

I receive message that no hints were displayed. Is it possible to configure MS Visual, that it recognize UI object?

To be specific, that 'list method' appears for objects created in code.

It would be really useful for me, because I designed a lot of in Qt Designer and it will be exhausting to keep all functions/attributes in mind... (QWidgets, QTextEdits, etc.)

I made research and had difficulties in locating similar problems in stackoverflow.com, could you please help me?

Regards,
krzysiek